# Convert select new to DataTable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, dataset

I am using .NET 3.5 and need to convert the below select new result into a DataTable. Is there  something built in for this or anyone know of a method that can do this?

```
var contentList = (from item in this.GetData().Cast<IContent>()
                  select new
                  {
                      Title = item.GetMetaData("Title"),
                      Street = item.GetMetaData("Street"),
                      City = item.GetMetaData("City"),
                      Country = item.GetMetaData("Country")
                  });
```

Comment: What are you doing that you need a DataTable as the result?

Comment: I am trying to export to CSV and already have methods that can export DataTable/Set to CSV.

Comment: I think you're looking for a dynamic programming language in a (mostly) statically typed one. If you're very attached to those DataTable to csv export routines, then I'm afraid your path might be one tread by only you. Anonymous objects are a fairly new language feature, and DataRow/DataTable/DataSet were not designed with them in mind.

Comment: More answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15213919/1180926

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy and straightforward thing to do is to use reflection:

```
var records = (from item in this.GetData().Cast<IContent>()
                           select new
                           {
                               Title = "1",
                               Street = "2",
                               City = "3",
                               Country = "4"
                           });
var firstRecord = records.First();
if (firstRecord == null)
    return;

var infos = firstRecord.GetType().GetProperties();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (var info in infos) {
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType);
    table.Columns.Add(column);
}

foreach (var record in records) {
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
        row[i] = infos[i].GetValue(record);
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Code may not be working up front but should give you a general idea. First, you get propertyInfos from anonymous type and use this metadata to create datatable schema (fill columns). Then you use those infos to get values from every object.

Comment: But Reflection is going to hit the performance every time the code runs. I would prefer to have specified the properties manually in the code.

Comment: Well, since OP is having 30+ properties and probably more than 1 use case, It'd be counter-productive to manually specify it. Also, there are tricks to make reflection more productive (like using the reflection only once and generating dynamic mapping method save in memory for future object conversion uses or fastreflection library).

Comment: Look at my generic solution without using Reflection instead using expression trees. Borrowed some code from your solution

Answer (score 3):

Here is one generic solution without Reflecting over the properties. Have an extension method as below

```
    public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>
                     records, params Expression<Func<TSource, object>>[] columns)
    {
        var firstRecord = records.First();
        if (firstRecord == null)
            return null;

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        List<Func<TSource, object>> functions = new List<Func<TSource, object>>();
        foreach (var col in columns)
        {
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
            column.Caption = (col.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
            var function = col.Compile();
            column.DataType = function(firstRecord).GetType();
            functions.Add(function);
            table.Columns.Add(column);
        }

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var function in functions)
            {
                row[i++] = function((record));
            }
            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        return table;
    }
```

And Invoke the same using where parameters will be the column name in the order you want.

```
var table = records.ConvertToDataTable(
                                        item => item.Title, 
                                        item => item.Street, 
                                        item => item.City
                                      );
```

Comment: The variable i never seems to change?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list result to datatable by the below function

```
   public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        foreach (T value in values)
        {
            if (table.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                foreach (var p in value.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    table.Columns.Add(p.Name);
                }
            }

            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            foreach (var p in value.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                dr[p.Name] = p.GetValue(value, null) + "";

            }
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`CopyToDataTable` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which does that for you. It lives in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

Comment: I was hoping I can use this, but I get a compile error: Error 109 The type 'AnonymousType#1' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Data.DataRow'.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a useful method for copying from objects, anonymous or otherwise, unless they descend from DataRow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Create your datatable.

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Street", typeof(double));


// get a list of object arrays corresponding
// to the objects listed in the columns
// in the datatable above.
var result = from item in in this.GetData().Cast<IContent>()             
             select dt.LoadDataRow(
                new object[] { Title = item.GetMetaData("Title"),
                              Street = item.GetMetaData("Street"),
                 },
                false);


// the end result will be a set of DataRow objects that have been
// loaded into the DataTable.
```

Original Article for code sample : [Converting Anonymous type generated by LINQ to a DataTable type](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/6d4e2579-f4b5-497c-ad00-7c347eb1f902)

EDIT: Generic Pseudocode:

```
void LinqToDatatable(string[] columns, Type[] datatypes, linqSource)
{
     for loop
     {
       dt.columns.add(columns[i], datatypes[i]);
     }

//Still thinking how to make this generic.. 
var result = from item in in this.GetData().Cast<IContent>()             
             select dt.LoadDataRow(
                new object[] { string[0] = item.GetMetaData[string[0]],
                               string[1] = item.GetMetaData[srring[1]
                 },
                false);


}
```

Comment: I actually have over 30+ properties and want this to be generic. Is there another way besides hard coding the columns? I might as well create a real class instead of using an anonymous one.

Comment: Check my edit. Still thinking on how to make the 2nd part generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> data)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
                dt.Columns.Add(prop.Name, prop.PropertyType);
            }
            object[] values = new object[props.Count];
            foreach (T t in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(t);
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

After you do your select new you can to `.ToList().ListToDataTable()`.  This uses ComponentModel reflection and is (theroetically) faster than System.Reflection.