# How to populate DataTable with anonymous LINQ result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, data-binding, ado.net

I have the following LINQ query:

```
var timesheets = from timesheet in entities.Timesheets
    join timesheetTask in entities.Timesheet_Task on timesheet.Id equals timesheetTask.Timesheet_Id
    join task in entities.Tasks on timesheetTask.Task_Id equals task.Id
    join project in entities.Projects on task.Project_Id equals project.Id
    join department in entities.Departments on project.Department_Id equals department.Id
    where timesheet.Employee_Id == employeeId
    select new
    {
       date = timesheet.Date,
       taskName = task.Name,
       projectName = project.Name,
       projectDesc = project.Description,
       departmentName = department.Name,
       taskEstimatedHours = task.Estimated_Hours,
       timesheetHours = timesheetTask.Hours
    };
```

How can I put these results into a DataTable which I can then bind to a DataGridView control?

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
    table.Columns.Add("date");
    table.Columns.Add("taskName");
    table.Columns.Add("projectName");
    table.Columns.Add("projectDesc");
    table.Columns.Add("departmentName");
    table.Columns.Add("taskEstimatedHours");
    table.Columns.Add("timesheetHours");

    foreach (var item in timesheets)
    {
        table.Rows.Add(item.date, item.taskName, item.projectName,
            item.projectDesc, item.departmentName, item.taskEstimatedHours,
            item.timesheetHours);
    }
}
```

**Update:** Here is my updated code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

using (PTMS_DataEntities entities = new PTMS_DataEntities())
{
    var timesheets = from timesheet in entities.Timesheets
                     join timesheetTask in entities.Timesheet_Task on timesheet.Id equals timesheetTask.Timesheet_Id
                     join task in entities.Tasks on timesheetTask.Task_Id equals task.Id
                     join project in entities.Projects on task.Project_Id equals project.Id
                     join department in entities.Departments on project.Department_Id equals department.Id
                     where timesheet.Employee_Id == employeeId
                     select new
                     {
                         date = timesheet.Date,
                         taskName = task.Name,
                         projectName = project.Name,
                         projectDesc = project.Description,
                         departmentName = department.Name,
                         taskEstimatedHours = task.Estimated_Hours,
                         timesheetHours = timesheetTask.Hours
                     };

    table.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Columns.Add("taskName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("projectName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("projectDesc", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("departmentName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("taskEstimatedHours", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("timesheetHours", typeof(int));

    List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>();
    foreach (var item in timesheets)
    {
        //table.Rows.Add(item.date, item.taskName, item.projectName,
        //    item.projectDesc, item.departmentName, item.taskEstimatedHours,
        //    item.timesheetHours);

        var row = table.NewRow();

        row.SetField<DateTime>("date", item.date);
        row.SetField<string>("taskName", item.taskName);
        row.SetField<string>("projectName", item.projectName);
        row.SetField<string>("projectDesc", item.projectDesc);
        row.SetField<string>("departmentName", item.departmentName);
        row.SetField<int>("taskEstimatedHours", item.taskEstimatedHours);
        row.SetField<int>("timesheetHours", item.timesheetHours);

        list.Add(row);
    }

    table = list.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Here is the SQL query I tested in SSMS (which should be the equivalent of the LINQ query):

```
SELECT dbo.Department.Name, dbo.Task.Name AS Expr1, dbo.Task.Estimated_Hours, dbo.Timesheet.Date, dbo.Project.Name AS Expr2, dbo.Project.Description, 
                  dbo.Timesheet_Task.Date AS Expr3
FROM     dbo.Department INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Project ON dbo.Department.Id = dbo.Project.Department_Id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Task ON dbo.Project.Id = dbo.Task.Project_Id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Timesheet_Task ON dbo.Task.Id = dbo.Timesheet_Task.Task_Id INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Timesheet ON dbo.Timesheet_Task.Timesheet_Id = dbo.Timesheet.Id
```

Comment: This was a very handy piece of code. I needed to get data from an anonymous object through a few layers of code (not my design). Thanks for posting the final product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to populate DataTable:

```
// your query
var timesheets = ...

// design table first
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn
    {
        ColumnName = "TaskName",
        DataType = typeof(String);
    });
...

List<DataRow> list = new List<DataRow>();
foreach (var t in timesheets)
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    row.SetField<string>("TaskName", t.taskName); // extension method from System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
    ...

    list.Add(row);
}

DataTable table = list.CopyToDataTable(); // extension method too
```

---

Or more LINQ way:

```
timesheets
    .Select(t =>
        {
            var row = table.NewRow();
            ...
            return row;
        })
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

---

Or in same query syntax. Implement a method:

```
static DataRow NewRow(DataRow row, string taskName, ....)
{
    ...
}
```

Then query itself:

```
(from ...
 where ...
 select NewRow(table.NewRow(), task.Name, ...)
).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Edited my original post to include what I currently have been trying. Could you possibly explain why the way I have it isn't working?

Comment: @ChrisV: I guess you need specify column table explicitly (see my code) otherwise it will be string and cause conversion error (`By default, the DataType for the new column is string`) from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/52xzw8tf.aspx)

Comment: Like so?  
  
        table.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));  
                table.Columns.Add("taskName", typeof(string));  
                table.Columns.Add("projectName", typeof(string));  
                table.Columns.Add("projectDesc", typeof(string));  
                table.Columns.Add("departmentName", typeof(string));  
                table.Columns.Add("taskEstimatedHours", typeof(int));  
                table.Columns.Add("timesheetHours", typeof(int));

Comment: @ChrisV: Use `tilde` as usually for one-line formatiing. Yes, [looks good](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/730zyedy.aspx). Does it work for you eventually?

Comment: No, not returning any results still...which is curious because I ran an equivalent query in SQL Server Management Studio and it *did* return results. :/

Comment: With the new code I just added it throws "The source contains no DataRows"

Comment: @ChrisV.: Make sure that `timesheets` contains records by calling `ToList()`. Then make sure that `List<DataRow>` contains items too. What line does throw this error?

Comment: Let me try that out. In the meantime, maybe it would be beneficial to confirm that the equivalent SQL query I tested in SSMS is, in fact, actually the same as the LINQ query...I've added the query to the end of my original post.

Comment: When I tried to use ToList() it told me "Cannot implicityly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Data.DataRow>'

Comment: @ChrisV.: Declare this temp list as just `var temp = bla.ToList();`

Comment: Hm...looks like the list is empty as well.

Comment: @ChrisV. Means that initials LINQ query returned no result. Debug which join ruins it.

Comment: How can I determine specifically which join is 'ruining' it?

Comment: Nevermind, seems I was looking for records for a user that had no existing records! >_<

Answer (score 3):

Call `.ToList()`.
The resulting `List<T>` can also be bound to a DataGridView, and is easier to work with than a DataTable.

Comment: Not all of the resulting data (columns) are of the same type, though. Won't that be an issue?

Comment: @ChrisV.: No; it's a strongly-typed list of the anonymous type shaped by your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [FastMember](https://code.google.com/p/fast-member/) for this purpose. It uses [IL instead of reflection](http://blog.marcgravell.com/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html) (much faster) to iterate over all of the property and field values automatically. Code sample from the site:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> data = ...
var table = new DataTable();
using(var reader = ObjectReader.Create(data))
{
    table.Load(reader);
}
```