# How can I convert each record from query result to arraylist c#

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist

Sorry as I am new to C# I want to convert each record retrieved from the DATABASE to arraylist 
my code is as follow:

```
var reservation = from x in db.resrvation \
                  where x.date=Calendar1.SelectedDate 
                  select x;
```

Here I want to get each record in reservation and convert it to array so i can gets specific   data e.g. client name

The collection retrieved by reservation include no. of records each of them have properties such as clintName, Phone, ReservationDate,..etc I want to make an arraylist for each record .

Actually I am trying to use this arraylist to fill datatable raw.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate DataTable with anonymous LINQ result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213919/how-to-populate-datatable-with-anonymous-linq-result)

Comment: First - don't use ArrayList, because it is not strongly-typed. Second - if you are querying reservations, then `r` is more appropriate name for query variable than `x`. And last - if you are returning list, then `reservations` is more appropriate name that single `reservation`

Comment: Thanks for this tips lazyberezovsky :)

Answer (score 3):

Just convert to `List` and you are done.

```
var reservations = (from x in db.resrvation 
                   where x.date=Calendar1.SelectedDate 
                   select x).ToList();
```

Comment: THanks 4 your reapid replay- the target is get an array list for each reservation and not array list contain all reservations so i can  fill the data table cell by cell ...i tried .toList but it will give a list conatin all reservations

Comment: @user2278268: why not array list contain all reservations? I didn't understand the problem. please explain a bit more. Thanks

Comment: can I retrieve specific detail from the object if it is arraylist contain all reservation

Comment: yes, you should. what detail you want to achieve and if there is any problem, let it know please.

Comment: as an eg i want to retrieve the clintName of the first reservation

Comment: It should be `((ReservationObject)reservations.FirstOrDefault()).clintName`

Answer (score 0):

Well, to convert it to an `Arraylist` you can do this:

```
(from x in db.resrvation where x.date=Calendar1.SelectedDate select x).ToArrayList();
```

Assuming you have this extension method:

```
public static ToArrayList(this IEnumerable source)
{
    var a = new ArrayList();
    foreach (object item in source) a.Add(item);
    return a;
}
```

However, I'd use a generically-typed `List<T>` instead, like this:

```
(from x in db.resrvation where x.date=Calendar1.SelectedDate select x).ToList();
```

Comment: THanks 4 your reapid replay-the target is get an array list for each reservation and not array list contain all reservations so i can  fill the data table cell by cell ...i tried .toList but it will give a list conatin all reservations

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to select an ArrayList for each row. Try this:

```
var reservation = from r in db.reservation
    where r.date == Calendar1.SelectedDate
    select new ArrayList(new object[] { r.name, r.whatever });
```