# how to merge duplicate records into one record by linq

Tags: sql, linq, datatable, merge

```
ID     Name   from       to
001-1  ABC    2015/05/01 2015/05/31
001-1  ABC    2015/06/01 2015/07/15
003-2  DEF    2015/05/01 2015/05/11
002-1  LMN    2015/05/01 2015/06/15
002-1  LMN    2015/06/16 2015/07/31
003-2  DEF    2015/06/01 2015/07/15
004-5  GHI    2015/05/11 2015/05/15
```

I want to have merge the records into one which matching the period from `2015/05/15` to `2015/07/15` like the following result in datable.

```
ID     Name   from       to 
001-1  ABC    2015/05/01 2015/07/15  
002-1  LMN    2015/05/01 2015/07/31
```

`003-2` and `004-5` are not in new datatable as they are not in the require range.

How can I get this? I only know very basic knowledge about LINQ and it's very fresh to me. thx.

Comment: It is not clear why `003-2`, `004-5` are not in the required range, whereas the other records are. All records seem to have similar date ranges. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: As I want to retrieve the record inclusive in the range of  "2015/05/15 to 2015/07/15". While 003-2 is disconnected during the period and 004-5 is end at 2015/05/15.

Comment: So `004-5` should end *at* or *after* `2015/07/15` ?

Comment: No as there is only one record "004-5  GHI    2015/05/11 2015/05/15". and it's end last appearnce date is 2015/05/15

Comment: So it's end should be ... ? when ? (so as to be included in the result)

Answer (score 0):

With this class / data as a mockup:

```
class Item
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}

List<Item> items = new List<Item> {
   new Item { ID = "001-1", Name = "ABC", 
              From = DateTime.Parse("2015/05/01"), 
              To = DateTime.Parse("2015/05/31") },
   new Item { ID = "001-1", Name = "ABC", 
              From = DateTime.Parse("2015/06/01"), 
              To = DateTime.Parse("2015/07/15") },
   new Item { ID = "003-2", Name = "DEF", 
              From = DateTime.Parse("2015/05/01"), 
              To = DateTime.Parse("2015/05/11") },
   new Item { ID = "002-1", Name = "LMN", 
              From = DateTime.Parse("2015/05/01"), 
              To = DateTime.Parse("2015/06/15") },
   new Item { ID = "002-1", Name = "LMN", 
              From = DateTime.Parse("2015/06/16"), 
              To = DateTime.Parse("2015/07/31") },
   new Item { ID = "003-2", Name = "DEF", 
              From = DateTime.Parse("2015/06/01"), 
              To = DateTime.Parse("2015/07/15") },
   new Item { ID = "004-5", Name = "GHI", 
              From = DateTime.Parse("2015/05/11"), 
              To = DateTime.Parse("2015/05/15") }
            };
```

you can use the following linq query to get the desired result set:

```
  var result = from i in items
               orderby i.From
               group i by new { i.ID, i.Name } into iGroup
               where iGroup.First().From <= DateTime.Parse("2015/05/15") && 
                     iGroup.Last().To >= DateTime.Parse("2015/07/1") &&
                     (iGroup.Last().To - iGroup.First().From).Days + 1 == 
                        iGroup.Sum(g => (g.To - g.From).Days + 1)
               select new Item
               {
                  ID = iGroup.Key.ID,
                  Name = iGroup.Key.Name,
                  From = iGroup.First().From,
                  To = iGroup.Last().To
               };
```

You can adjust datetime comparisons to fit your actual requirement. In the above linq query I am comparing the smallest `From` date and the largest `To` date of each group to the matching period dates.

This comparison:

```
(iGroup.Last().To - iGroup.First().From).Days + 1 == 
                            iGroup.Sum(g => (g.To - g.From).Days + 1)
```

checks for groups that have no gaps in their date ranges.

**EDIT:**

If the source data is stored in a `DataTable` such as:

```
 DataTable items = new DataTable();
 items.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
 items.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
 items.Columns.Add("From", typeof(DateTime));
 items.Columns.Add("To", typeof(DateTime));
```

then the linq query becomes a bit more complicated:

```
var q = from i in items.AsEnumerable()
        orderby i.Field<DateTime>("From")
        group i by new { ID = i.Field<string>("ID"), Name = i.Field<string>("Name") } into iGroup
        where iGroup.First().Field<DateTime>("From") <= DateTime.Parse("2015/05/15") &&
              iGroup.Last().Field<DateTime>("To") >= DateTime.Parse("2015/07/1") &&
              (iGroup.Last().Field<DateTime>("To") - iGroup.First().Field<DateTime>("From")).Days + 1 ==
              iGroup.Sum(g => (g.Field<DateTime>("To") - g.Field<DateTime>("From")).Days + 1)
        select new
        {
            ID = iGroup.Key.ID,
            Name = iGroup.Key.Name,
            From = iGroup.First().Field<DateTime>("From"),
            To = iGroup.Last().Field<DateTime>("To")
        };
```

The above query returns an `IEnumerable` of anonymous type. It can be converted back to a `DataTable` using Reflection (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937573/convert-select-new-to-datatable) post for example).

Comment: Really Thx for your solution! it's great it works. Btw, I would like to know if the source data is in datatable, how to modify to fit the code? Is it a must to create a glass for that? As I want the result store in the datatable finally.

Comment: @Donald Happy to help! Please check the edit I made.

Comment: I put the same data into datatable and use the datatable linq code. when I change the a shorter require range to "2015/05/01 ~ 2015/05/05". Strange that I found it generates different result. 
Result
Old code:  "001-1, 002-1, 003-2" is obtained 
Datatable code:  it shows only "001-1 and 002-1" only. 
It seems that only connected records are retrieved when using datatable code.

Comment: @Betsos, after several checking and different data combination. I found that both LINQ return only connected records even the require period range match in one of the condition e.g. "2015/05/01 ~ 2015/05/05" will not  include "003-2  DEF    2015/05/01 2015/05/11" even it's matched for the condition.

Comment: @Donald I am sorry but I cannot understand you. It is unclear what your requirements are as far as *period matching* is concerned.

Comment: @Betsos. 1st, I want to merge any connected records into 1 record. 2nd union with those disconnected records. 3rd query those union collection with require range. Base on your code, I can get all merged connected record as q and  (q.Union(items1.AsEnumerable().Where(p => !q.Any(p2 => p2.ID == p.ID)))).AsEnumerable().Where(i => (i.From <= DateTime.Parse(inDate) && i.To >= DateTime.Parse(outDate))) to get the desired result. However, i  need to make it as list of object instead working on datatable directly.

Comment: @Donald In my post I tried answering to the original question. However, it seems you need something different from what is described in the OP. So you need to either rephrase this question or delete it and post a different one that is as complete / self-contained as possible.