# Select a row from a DataTable and Create New Row to Add to DefaultView

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am trying to select a few rows from a datatable and check for certain conditions. Then I want to create a new row to convert the datatypes of two columns from a string which represents universal time to a string which represents local time and a string to an integer. Here is my code:

```
 dt = (from row in MV.Data.AsEnumerable()
       where !(row["conditionCodes"].ToString().Contains("%OC%"))
       orderby Convert.ToDouble(row["size"]) descending
       select new DataRow 
       {
         size = Convert.ToInt64(row["size"]),
         time = Convert.ToDateTime(row["time"]).ToLocalTime 
       }).CopyToDataTable();
```

This code doesn't work and doesn't like that I'm trying to create a new DataRow. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you want to create a new DataRow, `select new DataRow { size = ..., time = ...}` does not work.

It seems you try to mix using a constructor and [anonymous types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), or espacially you are trying to use an [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) on a DataRow.

Two things won't work out in this code:

1. Data row only has the [following constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx), `DataRow(DataRowBuilder builder)`, which requires a DataRowBuilder. Normally you create DataRows by calling [`DataTable.NewRow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Even if you could create a DataRow as you try it, the members `size` and `time` would not be known.

I suggest you to use one of the approaches in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937573/convert-select-new-to-datatable) by creating an anonymous type in your select clause and then converting the resulting IEnumerable to a DataTable, either by using refelection or using another approach.

```
var result = (from row in MV.Data.AsEnumerable()
              where !(row["conditionCodes"].ToString().Contains("%OC%"))
              orderby Convert.ToDouble(row["size"]) descending
              select new
              {
                size = Convert.ToInt64(row["size"]),
                time = Convert.ToDateTime(row["time"]).ToLocalTime 
              }
// Convert result to datatable using reflection, etc.
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you! That was very clear and cleared up some confusion I had.