# how to subtract two datatables?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

I want to subtract two datatables. What i want is that in below Image.

[image: Here is the Image]

I have the following code and i stacked at last point. Here is what i want to do in the code.

When i click Button1, it will get current data into firstDsData. A few seconds later when i click Button2, it will upload the current data to the secondDsData and merge it together. Then they will merge together into FinalDsData. Differences datatable will get the changes from finaldsdata.

The problem is in the last section. FinalDsData.GetChanges() doesn't work. It says nullreferenceexception. I also tried get changes with RowState.Unchanged/Modified(). They also didn't work.

```
    DataTable firstDsData = new DataTable();
    DataTable secondDsData = new DataTable();
    DataTable finalDsData = new DataTable();
    DataTable DifferenceDataTable = new DataTable();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataTable1TableAdapter.Fill(this.dataWE.DataTable1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        firstDsData = dataTable1TableAdapter.GetData();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secondDsData = dataTable1TableAdapter.GetData();

        finalDsData.Merge(firstDsData);
        finalDsData.AcceptChanges();
        finalDsData.Merge(secondDsData); //Until here i can get data into finalDsData. No Problem.
        DifferenceDataTable = finalDsData.GetChanges(); // Problem in here.Nullreferenceexception
        ultraGrid2.SetDataBinding(DifferenceDataTable, DifferenceDataTable.TableName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only goal is to show changes on a grid then you can use LINQ to find difference between two tables like:

```
var changes = (from dr1 in firstDsData.AsEnumerable()
    from dr2 in secondDsData.AsEnumerable()
    where dr1.Field<string>("Name") == dr2.Field<string>("Name")
    select new
    {
        Name = dr1.Field<string>("Name"),
        Value = dr1.Field<decimal>("Value") - dr2.Field<decimal>("Value")
    }).ToList();
```

To show it to your grid you can do:

```
ultraGrid2.DataSource = changes;
```

If you want a `DataTable` for the output then you can convert your LINQ results to a `DataTable`, see [Convert select new to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937573/convert-select-new-to-datatable)

Comment: I changed the code like this http://pastebin.com/Wkfkpjdw. It throws an error which says 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll' at begining of the 'select new'

Comment: @P.Exal, do you know the data type of second column `Value`, I assumed it to be decimal, it could be `double` or `float`, check the DataType and then replace that in the above code in place of `decimal`

Comment: thank you habib. it works. As a performance, is it efficient to use in this way ? This code runs everysecond.

Comment: @P.Exal, it depends on the `Data`, if there is too much data, than it might take some performance hit. This is for you to measure and decide. I am not sure if any other procedure of doing the same thing could bring significant performance gain

Comment: Hello. How can i get the values from toList linq for spesific row value? For example i just want to get 'Water' and want to show it into textbox

Comment: @P.Exal, you can add an extra check to compare if the value is actually equals to water something like `where dr1.Field<string>("Name") == dr2.Field<string>("Name") &&  dr1.Field<string>("Name") == "Water"`