# How to convert Linq select new to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

How to convert select new LINQ to DataTable
I need to compare several files using Windows Application form C#.
I have use LINQ and Lambda expression to sum up the duplicates
Please help thanks

I had seen [Convert select new to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937573/convert-select-new-to-datatable). and tried

```
 var firstRecord = records.First();
if (firstRecord == null)
return;

var infos = firstRecord.GetType().GetProperties();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
foreach (var info in infos) {
DataColumn column = new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType);
table.Columns.Add(column);
}

 foreach (var record in records) {
 DataRow row = table.NewRow();
 for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
     row[i] = infos[i].GetValue(record);
 table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

But it had errors for sequence contains no elements.

These are my full codes.

```
namespace Comparison2._0
{

public partial class ComparisonForm : Form
{
    public class FlatFile
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string Item_Type { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public ComparisonForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void UploadTransactionReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Multiselect = false;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String path = dialog.FileName;
            //String fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            TransactionFileNameTextBox.Text = path;
        }
    }

    private void UploadMovementReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Multiselect = false;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String path = dialog.FileName;
            //String fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            MovementReportTextBox.Text = path;

        }
    }

    private void UploadFlatfileReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Multiselect = true;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            String[] path = dialog.FileNames;
            //String fileName = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < path.Count(); i++)
                FlatfileTextBox.Text += path[i] + "@";

        }
    }

    private void UploadAdjustmentReportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Multiselect = false;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            String path = dialog.FileName;
            AdjustmentReportTextBox.Text = path;
        }
    }

    private void CompareButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OleDbConnection objConn, objConn1, objConn2;
        DataTable dt, dt1, dt2, TableA, TableB, TableC;
        string sql, sql1, sql2;
        OleDbDataAdapter oleDA;
        DataSet ds;

        string transactionReport = TransactionFileNameTextBox.Text;
        string movementReport = MovementReportTextBox.Text;
        string adjustmentReport = AdjustmentReportTextBox.Text;


        String sConnectionString1 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" +
            transactionReport + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";

        String sConnectionString2 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source="
            + movementReport + ";" + "Extended Properties =\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";

        String sConnectionString3 = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source="
            + adjustmentReport + ";" + "Extended Properties =\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";

        //TRANSACTION FILE
        objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString1);

        objConn.Open();

        dt = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        sql = "SELECT * from [Sheet$]";
        oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, sConnectionString1);
        ds = new DataSet();
        oleDA.Fill(ds);
        TableA = ds.Tables[0];
        objConn.Close();

        //dataGridView.DataSource = _DtTable;

        //MOVEMENT FILE
        objConn1 = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString2);

        objConn1.Open();

        dt1 = objConn1.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        sql1 = "SELECT * from [Sheet$]";
        oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, sConnectionString2);
        ds = new DataSet();
        oleDA.Fill(ds);

        TableB = ds.Tables[0];
        objConn1.Close();
        //dataGridView.DataSource = _DtTable1;

        //ADJUSTMENT FILE
        objConn2 = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString3);

        objConn2.Open();

        dt2 = objConn2.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        sql2 = "SELECT * from [Sheet$]";
        oleDA = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql2, sConnectionString3);
        ds = new DataSet();
        oleDA.Fill(ds);

        TableC = ds.Tables[0];
        objConn2.Close();
        //dataGridView1.DataSource = TableC;

        //FLATFILES
        //List<string> fileLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(FlatfileTextBox.Text).ToList();

        DataTable TableD = ConvertToDataTable(FlatfileTextBox.Text, 4);

        //dataGridView1.DataSource = tableD;

        DataTable FlatFileTable = new DataTable();
        FlatFileTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Location"));
        FlatFileTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Type"));
        FlatFileTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type"));
        FlatFileTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"));
        FlatFileTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(double)));
        FlatFileTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount Difference"));

        foreach (DataRow rowA in TableA.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow rowD in TableD.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDouble(rowD["Amount"]) > 0)
                {
                    if (rowA["Location"].ToString().Substring(0, 5).Trim() == rowD["Location"].ToString() && rowD["Type"].ToString() == "GRN" && rowA["Item Type"].ToString() == rowD["Item Type"].ToString())
                    {

                        var newRow = FlatFileTable.NewRow();
                        newRow["Location"] = rowD["Location"];
                        newRow["Item Type"] = rowD["Item Type"];
                        newRow["Type"] = rowD["Type"];
                        newRow["PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"] = rowA["PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"];
                        //sum += Convert.ToDouble(rowD["Amount"]);
                        newRow["Amount"] = rowD["Amount"];

                        var newSort = from row in FlatFileTable.AsEnumerable()
                                      group row by new { Location = row.Field<string>("Location"), Item_Type = row.Field<string>("Item Type"), Type = row.Field<string>("Type") } into grp
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          Location = grp.Key.Location,
                                          //Item_Type = grp.Key.Item_Type,
                                          Type = grp.Key.Type,
                                          Amount = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<double>("Amount"))
                                      };


                        //dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
                        //newRow["Amount Difference"] = Convert.ToDouble(rowA["PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"]) - Convert.ToDouble(rowD["Amount"]);
                        FlatFileTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
                        //FlatFileTable.Rows.Add(newSort.ToList());
                        //dataGridView1.DataSource = FlatFileTable;
                        //DataTable TableZ = newSort.Copt
                        dataGridView.DataSource = Comparison(TableA, TableB, FlatFileTable);

                    }
                }

            }

        }

        //dataGridView1.DataSource = FlatFileTable;
        //dataGridView.DataSource = Comparison(TableA, TableB, newSort.);
        //I want to pass into this function so I can compare between them
    }

    public DataTable ConvertToDataTable(string filePath, int numberOfColumns)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Type"));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(double)));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Location"));
        tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Type"));

        //foreach(var file in filePath)
        string[] MultipleFiles = filePath.Split('@');
        for (int i = 0; i < MultipleFiles.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(MultipleFiles[i]);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var cols = line.Split('|');
                var count = 0;
                DataRow dr = tbl.NewRow();
                for (int cIndex = 7; cIndex < 11; cIndex++)
                {
                    dr[count] = cols[cIndex];
                    count++;
                }

                tbl.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }



        return tbl;
    }

    public DataTable Comparison(DataTable A, DataTable B, DataTable C)
    {
        var tableC = new DataTable();

        tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Location"));
        tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Type"));
        tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"));
        tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qty Received Actual Cost"));
        tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount from FlatFile"));
        tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount (Transaction - Movement)"));
        tableC.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount (Transaction - FlatFile)"));

        foreach (DataRow rowA in A.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow rowB in B.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataRow rowC in C.Rows)
                {
                    if (rowA["Location"].ToString() == rowB["Location"].ToString() && rowA["Item Type"].ToString() == rowB["Item Type"].ToString() &&
                        rowA["Location"].ToString().Substring(0, 5).Trim() == rowC["Location"].ToString() && rowA["Item Type"].ToString() == rowC["Item Type"].ToString())
                        {
                            var newRow = tableC.NewRow();

                            newRow["Location"] = rowA["Location"];
                            newRow["Item Type"] = rowA["Item Type"];
                            newRow["PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"] = rowA["PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"];
                            newRow["Qty Received Actual Cost"] = rowB["Qty Received Actual Cost"];
                            newRow["Amount from FlatFile"] = rowC["Amount"];
                            newRow["Amount (Transaction - Movement)"] = Convert.ToDouble(rowA["PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"]) - Convert.ToDouble(rowB["Qty Received Actual Cost"]);
                            newRow["Amount (Transaction - FlatFile)"] = Convert.ToDouble(rowA["PO Total Cost(Qty Received)"]) - Convert.ToDouble(rowC["Amount"]);
                            tableC.Rows.Add(newRow);
                        }
                    //}
               }
            }
        }
        return tableC;
    }

    private void ComparisonForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it had errors for sequence contains no elements.

You are getting the above error because there is no record in the collection apparently and `First` fails in that case. You need `FirstOrDefault` which will return `null` if there is no items in the collection:

```
var firstRecord = records.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Okay, it doesn't have errors, but the dataGridView doesn't show any output, it's empty

Comment: @Cheeseburger make sure `records` have items in it