# Joining two data-table and save result in data-table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 datasets, I want to join two datasets and save the result in a datatable.

I am able to join the tables but while saving the result in datatable it is throwing an error 
**'Unable to cast object of type d__38 4[System.Data.DataRow,System.Data.DataRow,System.String,<>f__AnonymousType0 7[System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Int32,System.String,System.String,System.String]]' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'**

My Code:

```
private DataSet joindatasets(DataSet ds1, DataSet dsHeader)
        {
            DataTable dt; 
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
            DataTable dt1=new DataTable();

        dt1.Columns.Add("PracticeCode", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("PracticeName", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("High", typeof(int));
        dt1.Columns.Add("Medium", typeof(int));
        dt1.Columns.Add("username", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("MIAlertHeader", typeof(string));
        dt1.Columns.Add("MIAlertFooter", typeof(string));

        if (dsHeader.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= dsHeader.Tables.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                dt = dsHeader.Tables[i];

                var query = from table1 in ds1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                             join table2 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             on (string)table1["PracticeCode"] equals (string)table2["PracticeCode"]


                            select new
                            {
                                PracticeCode = (string)table1["PracticeCode"],
                                PracticeName = (string)table1["PracticeName"],
                                High = (int)table1["High"],
                                Medium = (int)table1["Medium"],
                                username = (string)table2["username"],
                                MIAlertHeader = (string)table2["MIAlertHeader"],
                                MIAlertFooter = (string)table2["MIAlertFooter"]
                            };
                dt1 = (DataTable)query;

            }
        }

        return ds;
    }
```

Please Help

Comment: They contain a common column PracticeCode on which I am applying inner joining, rest of the columns are different

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert select new to DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937573/convert-select-new-to-datatable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such of error quite often happens when you try to convert `IEnumerable<object>` to `DataRow`. To work-around this you have to use [DataTable.LoadDataRow method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.loaddatarow?view=netframework-4.7.2) + [CopyToDataTable method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
            dt1 = (from table1 in ds1.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                         join table2 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                         on (string)table1["PracticeCode"] equals (string)table2["PracticeCode"]
                        select dt1.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                        {
                            (string)table1["PracticeCode"],
                            (string)table1["PracticeName"],
                            (int)table1["High"],
                            (int)table1["Medium"],
                            (string)table2["username"],
                            (string)table2["MIAlertHeader"],
                            (string)table2["MIAlertFooter"]
                        }, false)).CopyToDataTable();
```

More details, you'll find here: [Creating a DataTable From a Query (LINQ to DataSet)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

Answer (score 0):

Create the following method and pass any type of object your LINQ query returning.

```
public static DataTable CreateDataTableFromAnyCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
        }

        foreach (T entity in list)
        {
            object[] values = new object[properties.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(entity,null);
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

and pass your LINQ result like

```
DataTable dt = CreateDataTableFromAnyCollection(list);
```

Comment: FYI: This is well beyond the scope required for this question, but I've extended your method to recursively evaluate types which contain complex properties, including collections. You can see [my implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72049096/generic-method-to-flatten-a-collection-of-nested-objects-into-a-datatable/72095768#72095768) on the question, "[Generic Method to Flatten a Collection of Nested Objects into a DataTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72049096/3025856)". This dramatically complicates the implementation, but may be useful for readers with more complex models.